# Error message when opening a copied workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I create a copy of a workbook and paste the values as Paste:=xlPasteValues
When I open the workbook with the xlPasteValues values, I get an error message (see attached picture).
What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much for your appreciated support.

```
Sub CopyPasteValuesInAllWorksheets()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Dim rng As Range
        
        LastRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                    
        LastColumn = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
        rng.Copy
        rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next ws
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    With Application
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Dim fName As Variant
    Dim currentDate As String
    
    currentDate = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("......\" _
    & "...." & " " & currentDate & ".xlsx", _
    "Excel files,*.xlsx", _
    1, _
    "Select your folder and filename")
    
    'exit procedure if the user didn't save the file
    If TypeName(fName) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fName, FileFormat:=51
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no image attached,you can probably use `rng.value = rng.value`

Comment: BTW, you'd better move "Application.CutCopyMode = False" right before "Next ws"